# queryEqual(toValue: true, childKey: "isFromCreator") not working?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch my data based on 2 things. First, fetch where `isFromCreator = true`. Second, fetch the results in terms of the latest 10.

My db structure looks like this:

```
ClubContent
     CreatorID
         clubID
            postID: {isFromCreator: Bool}
```

I then attempt to fetch this content like this:

```
        ref.child("ClubContent").child("jhTFin5npXeOv2fdwHBrTxTdWIi2").child("1622325513718")
        .queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
        .queryLimited(toLast: 10)
        .queryEqual(toValue: true, childKey: "isFromCreator")
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

**The result returned however is an empty snapshot. What is going wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `queryEqual(toValue:)` is not the key on which to filter, but the so-called disambiguation key. So if there are multiple node matching the value, the database finds the one whose key is equal to `childKey` and starts returning nodes from there.

So if you want to filter on `isFromCreator`, you will need:

```
ref.child("ClubContent").child("jhTFin5npXeOv2fdwHBrTxTdWIi2").child("1622325513718")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "isFromCreator")
    .queryEqual(toValue: true)
```

Then if there are multiple child nodes with `isFromCreator` equal to `true`, you can determine which one to start returning nodes from by passing its key as an extra value in to `.queryEqual(toValue:)`, for example:

```
    .queryEqual(toValue: true, childKey: "-Lasdnsa39132...")
```

---

It seems you're trying to sort/filter on two properties, which is not possible in the Realtime Database. Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property.

In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. You could for example have a property: `"isFromCreator_timestamp": "true_128348712"` and order/filter on that.

For another example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)